# 2008R2 How do I average the total scores summed?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How do I do the Average in this coding?

Sum(qa.greeting1+qa.greeting2+qa.greeting3+qa.greeting5+qa.greeting6) as AverageTotalCareScore

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a query already for a result set (100 rows?) so I would suggest doing something like a CTE to find the average of a result set.

```
WITH CTE AS(
<your query here>
)
SELECT 
AVG(column_to_be_averaged)
FROM CTE
```

Unless I misunderstood something, this should work out.

Comment: One more question...I added the convert (decimal(18,2) and for some reason it just returned 81.00 instead of 81.15....I must be missing something here?     Select 
CONVERT (DECIMAL(18,2),AVG( TotalCareScore))
from CTE

Comment: I figured it out! I had to do the convert decimal in the 1st query as well! HA! THANK YOU AGAIN!!!

Comment: I see you figured it out, but just to clarify on the 'why'--  When you use a common table expression you are telling the final SELECT to utilize the previous query as the source of the data, so if the source query (the CTE portion) doesn't have the converted value, converting it later on isn't going to do anything since the data has already been "snapshotted" from the table data in the CTE query using whatever data type scheme is default.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the average you can simply do like this:

```
select (qa.greeting1+qa.greeting2+qa.greeting3+qa.greeting5+qa.greeting6)/5
```

ie, sum of all the items divided by the number of items.

You can also use the AVG() function in SQL Server like this:

```
select AVG(column1)
```

Comment: hmmm. That didn't return to what I am looking for :/ this is the whole code if this helps. select --qa.ID,(qa.greeting1+qa.greeting2+qa.greeting3+qa.greeting5+qa.greeting6)/5 as TotalCareScore
from MEDD_Claims.dbo.tbl_ICare_Score qa
INNER JOIN MEDD_Claims.dbo.tbl_ICare_CallType ct
on qa.calltype = ct.ID
INNER JOIN MEDD_Claims.dbo.tbl_ICare_Client cc
on qa.clientID = cc.ID
INNER JOIN MEDD_Claims.dbo.tbl_ICare_Employee e
ON qa.coachId =  e.ID
where cc.contractname <> 'SilverScript'
and (qa.datescored >= '5/1/2015' and 
  qa.datescored <= '5/31/2015')

Comment: @HollyCathcart:- Then what you are looking for?

Comment: sorry I hit the enter button before providing you the whole code. What I have is 100 rows returned from the sum and now I need to average the whole 100 rows. Make sense?

Comment: select Distinct --qa.ID,SUM (qa.greeting1+qa.greeting2+qa.greeting3+qa.greeting5+qa.greeting6)as TotalCareScore from MEDD_Claims.dbo.tbl_ICare_Score qa INNER JOIN MEDD_Claims.dbo.tbl_ICare_CallType ct on qa.calltype = ct.ID INNER JOIN MEDD_Claims.dbo.tbl_ICare_Client cc on qa.clientID = cc.ID INNER JOIN MEDD_Claims.dbo.tbl_ICare_Employee e ON qa.coachId = e.ID where cc.contractname <> 'SilverScript' and (qa.datescored >= '5/1/2015' and qa.datescored <= '5/31/2015')